# Calling multiple variables integrated with HTML in PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have a question following my previous question: [Problem in displaying the WordPress shortcode function randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148669/problem-in-displaying-the-wordpress-shortcode-function-randomly)

As I asked in my previous question, I want to prevent the display of **duplicate shortcode** content on my content page **(for example, I may use this shortcode 5 times in one article and I don't want to have duplicate content in these 5 times**) And the codes in my previous question were correct, but now I want to integrate the values of the products into my previous code and I wrote the following code, but it is not correct and I get an error! **(I use these shortcodes in WordPress posts)**

```
function my_shortcode() {
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'return' => 'ids',
    );
    $all_products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $rnkeys = array_rand($all_products);
    $products_id = $all_products[$rnkeys];
    $product = wc_get_product( $products_id );
    
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $image = $product->get_image();
    $title = $product->get_title();
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    
    
    $values = [
        '1' => '
            <div>    
                <div>       
                    <a href="' .$link. '" title="' .$title. '" target="_blank">
                        <img src="' .$image. '" alt="' .$title. '">
                    </a>   
                    <span> '.$price.' </span>
                </div>    
            </div>
        ',
        '2' => '
            <div>    
                <div>       
                    <a href="' .$link. '" title="' .$title. '" target="_blank">
                        <img src="' .$image. '" alt="' .$title. '">
                    </a>   
                    <span> '.$price.' </span>
                </div>    
            </div>
        ',
        '3' => '
            <div>    
                <div>       
                    <a href="' .$link. '" title="' .$title. '" target="_blank">
                        <img src="' .$image. '" alt="' .$title. '">
                    </a>   
                    <span> '.$price.' </span>
                </div>    
            </div>
        ',
        
        /*
        '1' => '<a href="https://google.com"> <img src="img_1.jpg" /> </a>',
        '2' => '<a href="https://yahoo.com"> <img src="img_2.jpg" /></a>',
        '3' => '<a href="https://apple.com"> <img src="img_3.jpg" /></a>',
        '4' => '<a href="https://zdf.com"> <img src="img_4.jpg" /></a>',
        '5' => '<a href="https://air.com"> <img src="img_5.jpg" /></a>',
        '6' => '<a href="https://bing.com"> <img src="img_6.jpg" /></a>',
        */
    ];

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] = [];
    }

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) || ! is_array( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] = [];
    }

    $unused_values = array_diff( $values, $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] );

    if ( empty( $unused_values ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] = [];
        $unused_values                            = $values;
    }

    $key = array_rand( $unused_values );

    $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ][] = $unused_values[ $key ];

    return $unused_values[ $key ];
}
add_shortcode('jock', 'my_shortcode');
```

.

**Is there a solution that does not require me to repeat the arrays inside `$values` several times?!**

The problem with the above codes is that all the $values variable arrays return a product, and I think it's better to call the following codes in a separate function:

```
$args = array(
         'limit' => -1,
         'status' => 'publish',
         'return' => 'ids',
     );
     $all_products = wc_get_products( $args );
     $rnkeys = array_rand($all_products);
     $products_id = $all_products[$rnkeys];
     $product = wc_get_product( $products_id );

     $price = $product->get_price();
     $image = $product->get_image();
     $title = $product->get_title();
     $link = $product->get_permalink();
```

**I did the same, but the problem I have is that I don't know how to embed the html merged variables into the arrays.**

.