# Preventing the display of duplicate products in the WordPress shortcode and requesting code correction

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have a question following my previous questions: [Problem in displaying the WordPress shortcode function randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148669/problem-in-displaying-the-wordpress-shortcode-function-randomly) and [Calling multiple variables integrated with HTML in PHP arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152789/calling-multiple-variables-integrated-with-html-in-php-arrays)

As I asked in my previous question, I want to prevent duplicate shortcode content from appearing on my content page (for example, I may use this shortcode 5 times in an article and I don't want to have duplicate content in those 5 times. And Even if I had a total of 4 products and had used this shortcode 5 times and one less product would display an alternative text instead of displaying a duplicate product) and the codes of my previous question were correct, but now I want to integrate the values of the products in my previous code and the code What I wrote below is not correct because sometimes it displays duplicate products (I use these short codes in WordPress posts)

My code:

```
function get_product_id() {
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'return' => 'ids',
    );
    $all_products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $key = array_rand($all_products);
    $products_id = $all_products[$key];
    return $products_id;
}

function my_shortcode() {
    $products_id = get_product_id();
    $product = wc_get_product( $products_id );
    $product_price = $product->get_price();           
    $product_sale_price = $product->get_sale_price(); 
    $product_regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    if (isset($product_price) && $product_price > 0) {
        $product_price = number_format($product_price);  
    }
    if (isset($product_sale_price) && $product_sale_price > 0) {
        $product_sale_price = number_format($product_sale_price);  
    }
    if (isset($product_regular_price) && $product_regular_price > 0) {
        $product_regular_price = number_format($product_regular_price); 
    }
    $product_price_currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
    $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );  
    $product_title = $product->get_title();
    $product_link = $product->get_permalink();
    $discount = '';
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $max_percentage = 0;

        $percentage = 0;

        $price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale = $product->get_sale_price();

        if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) {
            $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
        }
        if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
        }
        
        if ($max_percentage <> 0) {
            $discount = '<div class="saved-sale">-' . round($max_percentage) . '% Off</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $product_regular_price = '';
    }
    
    
    $values = [
        '1' => '
            <a href="' . $product_link . '">
                <img src="' . $product_image . '">
                <span> '. $discount .' </span>
                <span> ' . $product_title . ' </span>
            </a>    
        ',
    ];

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] = [];
    }

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) || ! is_array( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] = [];
    }

    $unused_values = array_diff( $values, $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] );

    if ( empty( $unused_values ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] = [];
        $unused_values = $values;
    }

    $key = array_rand( $unused_values );

    $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ][] = $unused_values[ $key ];

    return $unused_values[ $key ];
}
add_shortcode('jock', 'my_shortcode');
```

Is this code correct and standard? If not, please tell me where the problem is and what changes should I make.

Is there a solution that does not require me to repeat the arrays inside `$values` several times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and you maintain a global array $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] to track which products have already been shown in the post.

I have revised your code please check:

```
function get_product_id() {
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'return' => 'ids',
    );
    $all_products = wc_get_products( $args );

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $used_products = isset($GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id]) ? $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id] : [];

    $unused_products = array_diff($all_products, $used_products);

    if(empty($unused_products)) {
        return null;
    }

    $key = array_rand($unused_products);
    $product_id = $unused_products[$key];

    $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id][] = $product_id;

    return $product_id;
}

function my_shortcode() {
    $products_id = get_product_id();
    
    if(!$products_id) {
        return "All products ";  
    }

    $product = wc_get_product( $products_id );
    $product_price = $product->get_price();           
    $product_sale_price = $product->get_sale_price(); 
    $product_regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    
    if (isset($product_price) && $product_price > 0) {
        $product_price = number_format($product_price);  
    }
    if (isset($product_sale_price) && $product_sale_price > 0) {
        $product_sale_price = number_format($product_sale_price);  
    }
    if (isset($product_regular_price) && $product_regular_price > 0) {
        $product_regular_price = number_format($product_regular_price); 
    }
    
    $product_price_currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
    $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );  
    $product_title = $product->get_title();
    $product_link = $product->get_permalink();
    $discount = '';
    
    if ($product->is_on_sale()) {
        $max_percentage = 0;
        $percentage = 0;
        $price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale = $product->get_sale_price();
        if ($price != 0 && ! empty($sale)) {
            $percentage = ($price - $sale) / $price * 100;
        }
        if ($percentage > $max_percentage) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
        }
        if ($max_percentage <> 0) {
            $discount = '<div class="saved-sale">-' . round($max_percentage) . '% Off</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $product_regular_price = '';
    }
    
    $output = '
        <a href="' . $product_link . '">
            <img src="' . $product_image . '">
            <span> '. $discount .' </span>
            <span> ' . $product_title . ' </span>
        </a>';

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'] = [];
    }

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) || ! is_array( $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] = [];
    }

    $values = ['1' => $output]; 

    $unused_values = array_diff( $values, $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ] );

    if ( empty( $unused_values ) ) {
        return "Alternative text";
    }

    $key = array_rand( $unused_values );

    $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][ $post_id ][] = $unused_values[ $key ];

    return $unused_values[ $key ];
}
add_shortcode('jock', 'my_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you @Jenny, it worked perfectly and without any problems!
`Are the codes I wrote standard and without problems?`

Comment: a question?
When does this condition become true?
`if ( empty( $unused_values ) ) {
         return "Alternative text";
     }`
I know when the variable `$unused_values` is empty I mean when does this variable `$unused_values` return an empty value?

Because the value of `$output` is a constant value, so I think this condition will never be true. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I asked this question to get more information, and I would be grateful if other friends know, to guide me.

Comment: $unused_values variable gets its value from the array_diff() function, which compares the array $values and $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id] and If all elements from $values have been used then array_diff() will return an empty array, and empty($unused_values) will return true. So, the condition if (empty($unused_values)) will become true when all the values from $values have been used at least once in the current post.

Comment: Thank you again
I did exactly the same thing, that is, to test if I have 5 products, I used the shortcode 8 times and it displayed 5 products, and then the command `return "All products";` displayed instead of 3 other products and the command `return "Alternative text";` did not display, so I wanted to know exactly when this value is called.

Comment: If the "Alternative text" is not being displayed, then $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id] is not being properly reset or managed, so $unused_values never becomes empty.

so you should check the $unused_values and check what you get 

error_log(print_r($unused_values, true));

Comment: The details of the `error_log` file, if I have a total of 2 products and use the shortcode 8 times, it will log the following values:

Comment: `[28-Sep-2023 16:54:36 UTC] Array
(
     [1] =>
<section class="block">
<div class="inside-block">
<a href="http://example.com/product1/" title="product1">
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/product01-300x150.png" alt="product1">
</a>
</div>
</section>

)

[28-Sep-2023 16:54:36 UTC] Array
(
     [1] =>
<section class="block">
<div class="inside-block">
<a href="http://example.com/product2/" title="product2">
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/product02-300x150.png" alt="product2">
</a>
</div>
</section>

)`

Comment: If the number of products is less than the number of shortcodes, only the return value `return "All products ";` returns instead of shortcodes that have no product.
I even removed all the products and used shortcodes, and instead of each product, the return value is `return "All products ";` was returned.


_These questions I ask do not mean that your guidance (your answer) is not complete, but to increase my knowledge, I like to learn and I hope you are not bothered by my questions._

Comment: Check $unused_values: Just like you used error_log(print_r($unused_values, true));, use it again but this time just before the if (empty($unused_values)) line. This will give you an exact snapshot. Make sure that the data types of the values in $values and $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id] are consistent. PHP's array_diff function compares types as well as values.

Comment: Ensure that $GLOBALS['my_shortcode_used'][$post_id] is correctly initialized, especially after all unique products have been displayed. Instead of if (empty($unused_values)), you could try if (count($unused_values) === 0). This checks more explicitly for an empty array. of $unused_values at the point where the empty check happens.